# Win32::API giving wrong prototype error

Tags: c, perl, winapi

Facing

> Win32::API a function was called with the wrong prototype and caused a C stack consistency EBP=18fde0 ESP=18fdd0

Below are the perl and C code

```
my $CheckSqlAnyWindow = new Win32::API($dllfile,
                   "CheckSqlAnyWindow", [ 'N', 'P', 'P' ], 'N');
    my $hwndSqlany = pack("L", 0);
    my ($i, $sqlanyWinId);
    START:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numRetries; $i++) 
    {

        $rc = $CheckSqlAnyWindow->Call($procId,"$engine - Adaptive Server Anywhere - 12.0.1 (3817)", $hwndSqlany);
        if ($rc <= 0)
        {
                $Cisco::DbUtils::errstr =  Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError());
                return 1;
        }
}
```

c Code

```
BOOL CheckSqlAnyWindow(DWORD pid, char *winTitle, DWORD * hwnd)
{
    StartDbInfo startDbBuf;
    BOOL rc;

    startDbBuf.pid = pid;
    startDbBuf.hwnd = NULL;
    strcpy(startDbBuf.winTitle, winTitle);

    rc = EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC) getWindowId, (LPARAM) &startDbBuf);
    memcpy((DWORD *) hwnd, (DWORD *) &startDbBuf.hwnd, sizeof(DWORD));
    return (TRUE);
}
```

Can anyone point out the correction to be done here please?

Comment: try `WINAPI` or `__stdcall` in the definition of your C function

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, you have different *calling conventions*. One key difference is who cleans up the stack space occupied by parameters and return value after a function is called. The standard calling convention used in C (and commonly called `cdecl`) leaves this work to the *caller*.

The Windows API functions use a different calling convention, named by Microsoft as `stdcall`. In this convention, the *callee* has the responsibility to cleanup the stack. As the perl module `Win32::API` is designed to call Windows API functions, this is the calling convention it uses by default.

The message you get supports this: `EBP=18fde0` and `ESP=18fdd0` are exactly 16 bytes apart from each other, that's the size of your function arguments plus the return value. As your function declaration doesn't have any attribute denoting a calling convention, it uses `cdecl`, so it doesn't do any stack cleanup at all, but `Win32::API` expected it to do.

One solution is to notify `Win32::API` of the calling convention.

```perl
Win32::API->new($dllfile, "CheckSqlAnyWindow", [ 'N', 'P', 'P' ], 'N', '__cdecl');
```

The other solution is change your library to use the `stdcall` convention.

```c
BOOL __stdcall CheckSqlAnyWindow(DWORD pid, char *winTitle, DWORD * hwnd)
```

Note that `__stdcall` is the notation adopted by MSVC, GCC, clang, probably some other compilers as well. Other compilers *might* use a different syntax for declaring a function as `stdcall`. You can avoid the whole issue by using the following since you include `windows.h`:

```c
BOOL WINAPI CheckSqlAnyWindow(DWORD pid, char *winTitle, DWORD * hwnd)
```

Comment: When no calling convention is specified in the C code, the compiler's default convention is used, which is *usually* `cdecl`, but may be something else, depending on the user's compiler setup. So you can't always assume `cdecl`, unless you never change the default.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the edit, I'm not familiar with `Win32::API` and so didn't know it supports `cdecl` as well.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks. _cdecl worked. But i am getting same error even when i use _cdecl. WE cant use WINAPI as this is windows dll.Below is the code
`my $CreateProcess =  new Win32::API("kernel32.dll", "CreateProcess",
      [ 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'N', 'N', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P' ], 'N');
    $rc = $CreateProcess->Call($dbengineCodeFile, $cmdLine, 0, 0, 0,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, ".", $startInfo, $procInfo);`
any suggestion for this?

Comment: Also worth noting: When targeting 64-bit, there is only a single calling convention. Thus, the issue auto-magically disappears, when writing 64-bit code.

Comment: @Prateek I really **don't** understand this comment, especially "*WE cant use WINAPI as this is windows dll*" ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen I mean that we dont have that code to change the method CreateProcess and create the dll.

Comment: @Prateek `CreateProcess` **is** a WINAPI call, so it already uses `stdcall` calling convention.

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes correct, but i am still getting **Win32::API a function was called with the wrong prototype and caused a C stack consistency EBP=18fde0 ESP=18fdd0** for this call

Comment: @Prateek in this case, your prototype **is** wrong. (Note that `BOOL` is a typedef to `int`, not to `long`, so according to [`Win32::API` docs](http://search.cpan.org/~acalpini/Win32-API-0.41/API.pm), you should be using `'I'` instead of `'N'`, but I guess there must be another problem)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Changed to `'I'` . didnt work. Got same error

Comment: @Prateek this was just an example and I already doubted it's the reason. Something apart from the snippet you show in your comment must still be wrong. Again, according to the docs, you should only write `kernel32`, not `kernel32.dll`, but this probably isn't the cause either.